# React Js how to handle props in child component

Tags: reactjs

I am new to React Js I am confused where I can get the props to manipulate it before its rendered to child component. Can anyone help me how it works?

Comment: i will suggest you to check the [**DOC**](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/components-and-props.html) for all the details about props.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a good and easiest example to understand the React Js life cycle.

[Click me](http://jsfiddle.net/mzabriskie/AZu8d/) to view sample and understand how it works.

```
var App = React.createClass({
getInitialState: function () {
    console.log('getInitialState');
    return {
        disabled: false
    }
},

getDefaultProps: function () {
    console.log('getDefaultProps');
    return {
        message: 'Hello World'
    };
},

componentWillUnmount: function () {
    console.log('componentWillUnmount');
},

componentWillMount: function () {
    console.log('componentWillMount');
},

componentDidMount: function () {
    console.log('componentDidMount');
},

componentWillReceiveProps: function () {
    console.log('componentWillReceiveProps');
},

shouldComponentUpdate: function () {
    console.log('shouldComponentUpdate');
    return true;
},

componentWillUpdate: function () {
    console.log('componentWillUpdate');
   },

    componentDidUpdate: function () {
        console.log('componentDidUpdate');
    },

handleMessageChange: function () {
    console.log('handleMessageChange');
    this.setProps({
        message: this.refs.message.getDOMNode().value
    });
},

handleDisabledChange: function () {
    console.log('handleDisabledChange');
    this.setState({
        disabled: this.refs.disabled.getDOMNode().checked
    });
},

    render: function () {
        console.log('render');
        return (
           <div className="container">
                <input ref="message"
                       type="text"
                       value={this.props.message}
                       disabled={this.state.disabled}
                       onChange={this.handleMessageChange}/>    
                <input ref="disabled"
                       type="checkbox"
                       checked={this.state.disabled}
                       onChange={this.handleDisabledChange}/>
               <div className="mirror">{this.props.message}</div>
           </div>
      );
   }
 });
```

React.renderComponent(, document.body);

Thanks.

Comment: Hmm...This looks easy to understand. Nicely explained.

Comment: If You got your problems solution then please accept the answer in your left side tick mark